# Kerberos and ssh multiple identities

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, kerberos, configuration-files

Perhaps the answer to this question is that it is not possible but hopefully someone knows how to get around this issue. In the past, before the admins configured Kerberos in our school machines I was able to create ssh keys for several purposes. The way this was done was via the `~/.ssh/config` file in my machine and the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` in the server. An example of my ssh config file goes as follows

```
Host sayHI
     IdentityFile path/to/sayHiPrivateKey
     HostName servername
     User myusername

Host sayHey
     IdentityFile path/to/sayHeyPrivateKey
     HostName servername
     User myusername
```

Then in the `authorized_keys` file I would have

```
command="echo hi" ssh-rsa sayHiPublicKeyLONGSTRING....
command="echo hey" ssh-rsa sayHeyPublicKeyLONGSTRING....
ssh-rsa otherkeysformypasswordlessentry
```

With this setup I could do something like

```
$ ssh sayHI
hi
$ ssh sayHey
hey
```

Unfortunately, this has now stopped since we are now using Kerberos to authenticate every day. What this means is that now I have do

```
$ kinit username@SERVERNAME
```

Once I put in my password I can use ssh as follows:

```
$ ssh -K username@hostname
```

and now I have access. If I do

```
$ ssh sayHi
```

this will not work since it asks for my password. If I do

```
$ ssh -K sayHi
```

this logs me in but it completely ignores the fact that this was supposed to use an identity so that I can run the command `echo hi`. Instead it just uses the kerberos credentials and logs me in. So now that I have explain the functionality that I once had, does anyone know if it is possible to recover this using kerberos and ssh? The multiple identities files was useful specially if you wanted to let a friend run a command on your behalf without giving them your password (http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch08_02.htm). I really hope this is still possible somehow. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Run "forced command" with your kerberos identity? Or authenticate to the server using public key, even if you have kerberos ticket? Both depends on how is the server configured.

Comment: @jakuje Both would be nice, I have no experience on how to do this or even if the current settings the server admin would allow it. Any pages that show how this is done?

Answer (score 0):

It depends if the server still accepts pubkey authentication or not (it looks like it does not, otherwise the kerberos authentication wouldn't make any sense).

Depending on the vendor of the OS, there might be possible to set up [.k5login](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.12/doc/user/user_config/k5login.html#k5login-5), but it will probably not solve the issue. Better way to differentiate between the commands would be using some alias on your client:

```
alias sayHi="ssh -K host echo Hi"
alias sayHello="ssh -K host echo Hello"
```

in your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: So with this setup it really makes it impossible to give access to people who are not users of the server without giving them your password. I miss the public keys.

Comment: Yes. It is good idea for security reasons. I don't know any valid reason I would like to give anyone access to my `ssh` (even with forced command).

Comment: Using your own private git repositories for instance.

Comment: It might be. But it was probably not the intentional use case for the server. You chance is to have a word with server administrator. There is nothing you can do about this from client side.